# Baking in Cycles - Texture messed up

Tags: texturing, uv, texture-baking, baking

I am a complete noob to baking, and I started by selecting Smart UV project to unwrap a cube, then changing the base colour in the shading panel. After, adding an image texture and creating a new image 500px x 500px (The size SL uses). The lighting setup is interior.exr on both the world shading and viewport shading. When baking on any setting the result is always multiple colours with white speckles.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/IS3h8.jpg

The setup (The image texture says "untitled" but there is usually an image in there.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/spVds.jpg

Any help?

Comment: If you dont think the colours are not just baked light and colour together, please share .blend file via https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and attach images directly into your Q via "edit". White spots can be common "white noise". To bake into image you have to select the image node. Also is this only one material set to the cube?

Comment: With your mentioned setup I got this https://imgur.com/7NMoqAP so there is something more than we can see from your description so blend please. Probably something with colour management?